# Mysql Like + Wild Card vs Equals Operator

Tags: mysql

I recently just fixed a bug in some of my code and was hoping someone could explain to me why the bug occurred.

I had a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field=13
```

Unexpectedly, this was returning rows where `my_field` was equal to either `13` or `13a`. The fix was simple, I changed the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field='13'
```

My question is, is this supposed to be the case? I've always thought that to return a similar field, you would use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field LIKE '13%'
```

What is the difference between LIKE + a Wild Card vs an equals operator with no quotes?

Comment: I would be interested to see what would be reason...

Comment: Thanks everyone. You all seem to be correct, sorry I can't choose you all :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement returns rows for `my_field = '13a'`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field=13
```

Because MySQL performs type conversion from string to number during the comparison, turning `'13a'` to `13`. More on that [in this documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html).

Adding quotes turns the integer to a string, so MySQL only performs string comparison. Obviously, `'13'` cannot be equal to `'13a'`.

The `LIKE` clause always performs string comparison (unless either one of the operands is `NULL`, in which case the result is `NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that since you didn't enclose it in quotes, and the column was a char/varchar column, MySQL tried to do an implicit conversion of the varchar column to an int.

If one of the rows in that table contained a value that couldn't be converted to an int, you would probably get an error.  Also, because of the conversion, any indexes you might have had on that column would not be used either.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with types and type conversion. With `my_field=13` , 13 is an integer, while `my_field` is in your case likely some form of text/string. In such a case, mysql will try to convert both to a floating point number and compare those.

So mysql tries to convert e,g, "13a" to a float, which will which be 13, and 13 = 13

In  `my_field = '13'` , both operands are text and will be compared as text using =

In `my_field like '13%'` both operands are also text and will be compared as such using LIKE, where the special % means a wildcard.

You can read about the type conversion mysql uses [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is because the MySQL type conversion works this way. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

It releases a warning as well. see the code below

```
    mysql> select 12 = '12bibo';
    +---------------+
    | 12 = '12bibo' |
    +---------------+
    |             1 |
    +---------------+
    1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

    mysql> show warnings;
    +---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
    | Level   | Code | Message                                    |
    +---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
    | Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '12bibo' |
    +---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Looks like someone raised a bug as well: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42241