# Mysql column = 1 and column like "1_" are equivalent?

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql query.

```
SELECT tanulok.nev, tanulok.osztaly, leadasok.idopont, leadasok.mennyiseg
FROM `leadasok`, tanulok 
WHERE tanulok.tazon = leadasok.tanulo and osztaly LIKE "1_"

SELECT tanulok.nev, tanulok.osztaly, leadasok.idopont, leadasok.mennyiseg 
FROM `leadasok`, tanulok
WHERE tanulok.tazon = leadasok.tanulo and osztaly = 1
```

They give the same result. Why?

column = 1 and column like "1_" are equivalent?

the values of the osztaly column are "1A", "1B", "2A" ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Like + Wild Card vs Equals Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609073/mysql-like-wild-card-vs-equals-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Because in MySQL to make a comparison of string and number - the DB engine converts the string into a number. It starts on the left side of the string and takes all number characters and builds a number from it.

```
"1A"       -> 1
"300miles" -> 300
"$3"       -> 0    (because the string does NOT start with a number)
```

That is why the second query returns results as well.